# Repopulate a combo box

Tags: c#, mono, gtk

This is how I populate the combo box:

```
        foreach(string s in entries)
        {
            string[] fields = someSplit(s);
            threadComboBox.AppendText(fields[0]);
        }
```

How would I remove all items and add new ones? I tried calling `Clear()`, but while it does remove old values, new ones don't get added.

Comment: What is `threadComboBox`? A short but complete example would be helpful...

Comment: A `ComboBox` containing some threads (as in, topics on a bbs).

Comment: Are you calling `Clear()` *before* you go through your `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
    threadComboBox.Clear();
    ListStore store = new ListStore(typeof (string));
    threadComboBox.Model = store;

    foreach(string s in entries)
    {
        string[] fields = someSplit(s);
        store.AppendValues (fields[0]);          
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer did not work for me by itself. I had to use the snippet from the [FAQ](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/gtk/#how-do-i-fill-a-gtkcombobox):

```
cb.Clear();
CellRendererText cell = new CellRendererText();
cb.PackStart(cell, false);
cb.AddAttribute(cell, "text", 0);
ListStore store = new ListStore(typeof (string));
cb.Model = store;

//now this works:
cb.AppendText("test");
```