# MONO GTK#: Trying to remove text in ComboBox and then prepend new text to the ComboBox but some of the old text remains

Tags: c#, combobox, mono, gtk, gtk#

I am trying to first remove everything in the ComboBox. And then prepend text to it, but some of the old text remains. Is there a way to RESET or CLEAR the ComboBox? Or how can I best achieve this?

```
public void GetBadgeName ()  
{  
     try  
    {  

    int i = 0;
    while (i < 200)
        {
            cmb_SelectBadge.RemoveText(i);
            ++i;
        }

   string connectionString = "URI=file:SIGN.sqlite";
   IDbConnection dbcon;
   dbcon = (IDbConnection) new SqliteConnection(connectionString);
   dbcon.Open();
   IDbCommand dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();

   string sql =
      "SELECT BadgeName " +
      "FROM Badge";
   dbcmd.CommandText = sql;
   IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();

   while(reader.Read()) {
    string BadgeName = reader.GetString (0);

    cmb_SelectBadge.PrependText(BadgeName);

            }

   reader.Close();
   reader = null;
   dbcmd.Dispose();
   dbcmd = null;
   dbcon.Close();
   dbcon = null;
    }         
    catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);    

        }
    }
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/27677350/67824

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out. Simply create a new empty ListStore (I call it ClearList) and then make the combobox.Model equal to the ClearList. Then prepend or append the text as normal to the combobox.

```
 ListStore ClearList = new ListStore(typeof(string),typeof(string));
 cmb_SelectBadge.Model = ClearList;

 // This example retrieves each BadgeName from the Badge table (see question)
 while(reader.Read()) {
     string BadgeName = reader.GetString (0);
     cmb_SelectBadge.PrependText(BadgeName);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try combobox.Clear(). You can find docs for Gtk# at http://docs.go-mono.com/

Comment: I have tried ComboBox.Clear(). It removed all text but the 'fields' are still there in 'whitespace'. Also, when im trying to prepend text again to the combobox after the clear() it does not show any text.